# Creating .bat file to automate multiple installations with install parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, windows-installer

Trying to create a .bat file to automate the installation of multiple programs, one after the other.

**I know there are many threads that address this issue, however, I have a slightly more specific question..:**

How would I cause the .bat file to fill out the install options for me? Options such as what directory to install to (so I can install to something other than the default directory), radio buttons involved in the installation (Default Installation / Custom Installation, etc.).

**Are there specific .bat file commands that would let me script the answers to the questions the installer(s) ask me?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Depends on the installer and the command-line options it gives you.  Scripting a GUI is beyond Batch's intention/capabilities (short of combining it with other utilities).  So if yo need help with a specific installer, perhaps we can help, but as-is this it too broad (IMO).

Comment: For example, with .msi installers you can code a line such as: msiexec /passive TARGETDIR="C:\MyTagretDirectory" /i MyProject.msi. Do these lines actually fill out the 'install directory' part of the installer GUI or do they bypass/override the installer program entirely? Reapply the above example to the question asked in the initial post.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: 'Make it relevant to others': Criticizing other's posts always pushes the post off topic... Also, no one asks this question. The question, put succinctly: write .bat file to install multiple programs with commands present in the .bat file to fill out fields in the installer GUI... IF such a thing is possible. That's a very precise post. Yes, I'm fully aware that if answered this post should prove useful to others. It appears top of Google's searches on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create a batch file, I would try to use a Setup Information file, or a .INF

The Microsoft Hardware Dev Centre has outlined a great how-to series that goes into great detail about the subject, either for fresh install or for the installation of software and drivers.  However, it is more commonly used for the latter.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/install/overview-of-inf-files

For the creation of INF-based installations you will want to use a tool known as IExpress.

It is quite a meaty subject, but, if you have the time to devote to it, it should serve to exponentially increase your knowledge of the Windows architecture.

"Options such as what directory to install to (so I can install to something other than the default directory), radio buttons involved in the installation (Default Installation / Custom Installation, etc.)."

These things can all be taken care of with a properly written XML file.  It is unclear how you intend to install said programs.  Do you have DLL's that accompany them?  IF you have these assemblies, another approach would be to use that XML file with the proper DLL's (or side by side assemblies) and to create what is known as a manifest.

Every manifest MUST have a side by side assembly associated with it.

In summary, your best bet is to go the .INF route and if you are skilled enough using XML terminology to try that approach.